# Attributes.Add() method in TagBuilder not working inside foreach()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, foreach, tagbuilder

`Attributes.Add()` method in `TagBuilder` not working inside `foreach()` loop and I am getting this error "There is already an entry with the same key".Also `SetInnerText()` method and `Attributes[key]` and property returns only one row inside `foraech` loop.

```
var select = new TagBuilder("select");
var option = new TagBuilder("option");

foreach (var country in Countries)
{
    option.Attributes.Add("value",country.Id.ToString());
    option.SetInnerText(country.Country);
}

select.InnerHtml = option.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
select.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
```

Comment: You are setting the same attribute of a single tag in a loop. You should probably create the tag in the loop also.

Comment: I think, TagBuilder Attributes.Add() support only unique key.Therefore i got that error, "There is already an entry with the same key".Thanks for aid @Ufuk.Solution;

var select = new TagBuilder("select");
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var country in Countries)
{
    sb.Append("<option value=\"" + country.Id.ToString() + "\">" + country.Country + "</option>")
}

select.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
select.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);